# Creating a role in a role

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I made a spring boot user management app and every time I update the user, the role doesn't overwrite.
Like this: roles=[Role{name='Role{name='ROLE_USER'}'}]}
roles=[Role{name='Role{name='Role{name='ROLE_USER'}'}'}]}

What can I change in my code to be just a Role;

User.class :
`

```
package com.webusermanagement.entity;


import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="enabled")
    private Boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public User(){}

    public User(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, boolean enabled, Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, boolean enabled) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public User(String username, String password, Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", enabled=" + enabled +
                ", roles=" + roles +
                '}';
    }
}
```

t`

Role.class:
`

```
package com.webusermanagement.entity;


import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Role(){}

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Role{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

`

UserDAOImplementation.class
`

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImplementation implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public User findByUserName(String username) {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        // now retrieve/read from database using username
        Query<User> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from User where username=:uName");
        theQuery.setParameter("uName", username);
        User theUser = null;
        try {
            theUser = theQuery.getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            theUser = null;
        }

        return theUser;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteByUsername(String username) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query query=session.createQuery("delete from User where username=:userName");
        query.setParameter("userName",username);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query query=session.createQuery("from User");
        List<User>users=query.getResultList();
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        currentSession.update(user);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: why you have multiple roles for one user ? should it be `@ManyToOne` ? and also you can added `mappedBy` like this -> `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "User", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`